# Use Websockets or ajax with timeout when waiting for database updates?

Tags: ajax, playframework, websocket

My app is updated when any events occurs, by adding an entry in the database.
This is done asynchronously via an independent code.

Now, using PlayFramework(Java), I'd like to display to the clients the events, listed in reverse chronological order (newest first).

I initially thought about using a websocket that the frontend would connect to, but that would require that the servers queries the database every n minutes to check for new entry, and return them if they exists.

I'm starting to wonder if making an ajax request with a `setInterval` wouldn't be a better/simpler alternative (with the same idea in mind: query the api to ask the latest events starting from date = {last query time}).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you had better think of making it event-driven instead of making periodic query considering performance and architecture if possible. The first thing is to notify your application server based on Play of changes of database by using that DBMS's trigger (AFAIK, some DBMS provides executing web service through trigger but I'm not sure it is desired or not) or the original application's listener like @PostPersist (If it's on the same Java process, you can utilize some static or DI-powered listener. If not, you can perform HTTP request).

Now that you are listening to database's changes, you need a way to notify interested clients of that change. You can choose any technologies called WebSocket or Comet to do that. However, the easiest choice is to adopt well-made framework for such usage in my opinion. As I'm the author of [Cettia](http://cettia.io), I give you an example written in Cettia but you can do that similarly with other projects like [atmosphere-play](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-play).

```
// Assumes you are notified of database changes through this listener
// However, it doesn't matter
public class SomeEntityListener {
    // Assumes you are using Dependency Injection framework like Spring or CDI
    // so you can inject io.cettia.Server to anywhere you want to handle clients
    @Inject
    Server server;

    // This method is called after persisting of some entity
    @PostPersist
    public void postPersist(SomeEntity e) { 
        // Broadcasts just a persisted entity to interested clients
        // No matter how you are notified of database event, only this line is necessary
        server.byTag("someentity-subscribers-postpersist", e);
    }
}
```

For how to install Cettia, see [this quick start guide](http://cettia.io/projects/cettia-java-server/1.0.0-Alpha1/#quick-start) and [a working example for Play](https://github.com/cettia/cettia-examples/tree/master/archetype/cettia-java-server/platform/play2). Of course, you can do that with vanilla WebSocket but it's not silver bullet. (And that's why so many frameworks arose in various languages and platforms)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your 1st choice was better as it would not require polling every n minutes because your application is running on a server that can be notified using some API that would be triggered when database is updated.

Websocket will create a channel between browser and play application that would comprise of 2 channels, one for inbound and one for outbound. on backend in play application while creating a websocket, we can attach a event listener to inbound channel that would trigger a callback depending upon data received in inbound channel from browser side.

So we can create an API that would be triggered from database on updation, that API will write data on outbound channel of websocket.

Using this approach will help you remove extensive polling on database.